# django-storages S3 Backend Won't Load

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto

I have a Django app that runs just fine on my localhost as well as on my Linode Ubuntu server.

I am running

```
django==1.4.2
django-storages==1.1.6
boto==2.8.0
Python==2.7.2+
```

From the Django shell on my **localhost**, I type:

> from S3 import CallingFormat

It works just fine. However, when I type that into the Django shell on the **server**, I get

> No module named S3

Am I missing something? Thank you in advance for any help you guys can offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like setup.py doesn't install S3 module in `PYTHONPATH`.
This can be easily fixed by downloading S3 module anywhere in your `PYTHONPATH` (type `import sys;print sys.path` to find these folders):

```
sudo curl -O https://bitbucket.org/dziegler/django-storages/raw/9a3017a4f577a7d740451c1a6dde9079c69f09b6/S3.py
```

That helped me

Comment: For reference this file has now moved to [GitHub](https://bitbucket.org/dziegler/django-storages/raw/9a3017a4f577a7d740451c1a6dde9079c69f09b6/S3.py)